# SVM: can you determine the which kernel function is the best to use given the margins length?

Tags: machine-learning, svm, inference

This is a bit of a theoretical question that I thought about the other day...

Assuming I got 2 SVM classifiers that were obtained by using different kernel functions, can I determine which one will perform better by just seeing which one has the widest separation margins?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [...] can I determine which one will perform better by just seeing...

No. You can never know which model performs better *a priori*. That's [the No Free Lunch theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No_free_lunch_theorem). You can infer their relative performance only *a posteriori*, and you can estimate it using nested cross-validation, but that gives no guarantees.